# ElGamal Digital Signature Scheme question

Tags: cryptography

Use the ElGamal Digital Signature Scheme in the group $G$ = $F^{×}_{p}$ = <g> where
$p$ = $479$ is prime and $g$ = $13$. Your secret signing key is $x = 300$. If you choose an
ephemeral key k = 11, what is the signature of your message m = 379?

I followed these steps and thought I had done nothing wrong but when I checked my answer by trying to verify, it was wrong.

First of all, I worked out $r ≡ g^{k}$ (mod $p$) by fast modular exponentiation to get $r ≡ 237$.

Next, I worked out $m ≡ xr + ks$ (mod $p-1$) and plugged in numbers to get 
$379 ≡ 300 * 237 + 11s$ (mod $478$), which rearranged to 
$11s ≡ 23$ (mod $478$)

I used Euclid's Algorithm to find the inverse of $11$, which I got as $89$, which meant
$s ≡ 89 * 23 ≡ 135$ (mod $478$) was the signature, or I thought was the signature.

When I went to verify my answer by working out $g^{m}$ (mod $p$) and $y^{r} * r^{s}$ (mod $p$),
(I had already worked out the public key $y ≡ g^{x}$ (mod $479$) before and it was $168$)
I expected to get the same number however I got $13^{379} ≡ 370$ (mod $479$) and $168^{237}$ * $237^{135} ≡ 357$ (mod $479$), which meant my signature was wrong.

Can anyone see an error I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $s$ that satisfies
$$
379 = 300\cdot 237 + 11\cdot s\mod 478
$$
is $s=89$, as computed. (And **not** $89\cdot 23$.)

Using the [wiki terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) we now have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p &= 479      &&\text{chosen prime}\\
F &= \Bbb F_p &&\text{associated field for algebraic computations}\\
G &= \Bbb F_p^\times &&\text{associated group for algebraic computations}\\
A &= \Bbb Z/(p-1) &&\text{additive group with same structure as $G$}\\
&&& \text{via }A\to G\ ,\ a\to g^a\text{ isomorphism}\\
|F| &= p = 479\\
|G| &= p-1 = 478\\
x &= 300\in \Bbb Z      &&\text{chosen private key, we may see $x\in A$}\\
y &= g^x=168\in G\subset F      &&\text{resulted public key}\\
m &= 379\in\Bbb Z      &&\text{message}\\
H(m) &= 379\in A &&\text{message $m$ seen in $A=\Bbb Z/(p-1)$, by using the}
\\
&&&\text{cryptographic hash $H$, passing modulo $(p-1)$}\\
k &= 11\in\Bbb Z &&\text{chosen random ephemeral, we may see $k\in A$}\\\\
r &= g^k=237\in G\subset F &&\text{and we must chose a lift}\\
r &= 237\in\Bbb Z\\
s &= (H(m) -xr)k^{-1}&&=89\in A\\
(r,s)&=(237, \ 89)\in\Bbb Z\times A&&\text{the final signature}
\end{aligned}
$$
To verify the signature, we have to check the relation:
$$
g^{H(m)} = y^r\; r^s\qquad\text{ in }G\subset F=\Bbb F_p\ .
$$
And in our case, working in the field $F=\Bbb F_p$ we have

- $g^{H(m)}=g^m=13^{379}=370\in G\subset F$,
- $y^r\; r^s=168^{237}\cdot 237^{89}=233\cdot 201 =370\in G\subset F$ .

Comment: Thank you so much, spent loads of time confused where I thought I was making a mathematical error and it was just this simple. I'm definitely not gonna make this mistake again now as well.

Comment: Please always ask, no hesitation, such questions show up very often, discussions are always useful. I also **learned from the question** how the procedure works in practice! Thanks a lot! Having explicit data (numbers as those for $p,g;x,k;m$ that give a clear sample situation) makes general discussions (as exposed in the cited wiki) easier to follow and see in action. I answered, since the question was clear, and going straightforward to the point (plus one for this reason!) - as presented i could immediately figure out where to start checking / chasing the error.